# Extract the values from the json object to the purpose of intent

Tags: java, android, json, string

According to the code sample I have shown, responseJson returns the value of FirstName. I want to get that value out of responseJson because i want to pass it to next activity. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            String myResJson;
            try {

                myResJson = responseJson.getString("Status");
                String test = myResJson;
                if (test.equals("200")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, ActivityMenu.class);

                    intent.putExtra("FirstName", firstname);
                    contxt.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(contxt,
                            "Login Error, invalid Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

this is the my responseJson value `{"LastName":"A","UserID":"1","Status":"200","FirstName":"P"}`

Comment: what problem you are getting ?? also add json string with question

Comment: responseJson has the value of FirstName, (responseJson is the  response im getting from API) i want to assign it to firstname, so i can use in my next activity.

Comment: what problem you are getting ?

Comment: firstname value is equall null, i want to get the FirstNamevalue which im getting from the responseJson .

Comment: @John : then show responseJson value in question to check what is in JSON and what you are trying to get value

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K, check my updated question please

Comment: I don't see you get the value for FirstName. It will be something like this: `responseJson.getString("FirstName");`

Comment: @JohnDavid: where you are getting name from json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
intent.putExtra("FirstName", firstname);
```

to

```
intent.putExtra("FirstName", responseJson.getString("FirstName"));
```

**OR**

```
firstname=responseJson.getString("FirstName");

if(firstname!=null)
    intent.putExtra("FirstName", firstname);
```

Comment: firstname=responseJson.getString("FirstName");

if(firstname!=null) intent.putExtra("FirstName", firstname);  this part worked for me

Comment: You were not parsing the string and just passing the null string in the intent. You always have to parse each string to be able to use it's value, just parsing Status would only give you status's value and not the whole data. Keep this in mind while parsing in the future. Glad to help :)

Comment: Tushan, thnx alot for ur kind advice. Im doing my first android project and learning lot of new stuff

Comment: Tushar*, keep it up. Android is fun.